# How can I use Samsung Apps in CyanogenMod 11?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4, stock-rom

I got my Galaxy S4 today (i337M), it's wayyy better than my old SII hehe.

I immediately removed the stock Bell firmware and put the latest snapshot available from CyanogenMod.

I'm wondering if it's possible to convert apps like S Planner, S Note, S Health to CyanogenMod.

Current stock android version available for i337M is 4.2.2.
Latest Android version for CM is 4.4.

If I install CM 4.2, can I import/install the APKs and then upgrade to 4.4?

Hope you'll be able to help me :)

Comment: Or if you know good alternative to those? (Because what's the point installing CM if I install all the stock crap coming with the phone lol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Samsung apps will not work on CyanogenMod because they are TouchWiz-based. CyanogenMod is AOSP-based. You would need to flash a stock ROM, or any custom ROM that is TouchWiz-based.

Comment: Oh I see - and that make sence... even if it's stupid haha. Thanks for clarifying that :)

Answer (score 0):

its about kernel. There are stock based touchwiz kernels and other cwm based kernels.

But for some phones like my old N7000 there are hybrid kernels too thanks to some XDA devs.